# How to display many differents values splitted by a new line in one cell

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'been trying to figure this out but can't. 
I've got a model which has let's say a one-to-many relationship.

```
        public virtual IList<ListModels.listaIdInstrumentos> listaIdInstrumentos { get; set; }
```

A pretty plane controller:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        informeModelContext db = new informeModelContext();
        var model = db.Informe.ToList(); 
        return View(model);
    }
```

And a scaffolded View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.listaCalibracion)
        </td>
```

...

The "listaCalibracion" is a List of string that for example could be something like 2 strings named "ABC" and "XYZ"
although i CAN display the values correctly in my page, it will display ("ABCXYZ") and what i want to show is (ABC /n/n XYZ) meaning one under another.

Sorry if i can't make myself clear. English is not my first Lenguage.
Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: can you try something like this
 `<td>
            @foreach (var listItem in item.listaCalibracion)
            {Html.DisplayFor(listItem); <br/>}
            </td>`

Comment: Thanks! your comment help me to solve this!

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @foreach (var subItem in item.listaCalibracion)
    {        
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => subItem )
            </td>
```